# Cheerio: Loop over children with tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am attempting to loop over the children of a `tag` and I want to retain their respective `tags`. For example:

```
<div class='main'>
    <p>First p</p>
    <div class='1'>Div 1</div>
    <div class='2'>Div2 <p>Another P</p></div>
</div>
```

I would like to loop over the children like so:

```
<p>First p</p>
<div class='1'>Div 1</div>
<div class='2'>Div2 <p>Another P</p></div>
```

The code I am attempting is like so:

```
const block = body.find('div.main')
const children = block.children().each((i, el) => {
   console.log("===")
   console.log($(el).html()) //Also tried $(this).html(), but returns null
})
```

Results:

```
===
First p
===
Div 1
===
Div2 <p>Another P</p>
```

But the result gives me everything **inside** each child, which is not what I want. I would like to retain their respective `<p>` or `<div>` tags.

Other attempts of using `outerHTML` somehow doesn't seem to work, ie they all returned `undefined`. Things I have tried:

```
console.log($(el).prop('outerHTML'));
console.log($(el).outerHTML);
console.log($(el)[0].outerHTML);
```

Comment: Try using 'childNodes' instead of 'children' and filter out non required nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using `cheerio.html($(el))` instead, that is as indicated in their documentation [here](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#rendering)

This achieve a very similar result to `outerHTML`.